# Proof that a compact surface in a ball of radius $r$ has at least one point $p$ such that $K(p) \geq1/r^2$ and $|H(p)| \geq 1/r$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Consider the following problem (Exercise (2) in the end of Chapter 3 of *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd Edition, by Montiel and Ros):

> Let $S$ be a compact surface contained in a closed ball of radius $r > 0$. Prove that there exists at least one point $p \in S$ such that $K(p) \geq 1/r^2$ and $|H(p)| \geq 1/r$.

The book provides the following solution to this problem:

Let $a$ be the centre of the ball of radius $r$ in which $S$ is contained. By compactness, there is some $p \in S$ such that the square of the distance to $a$ attains a maximum. Then we know that $a$ is in the normal line of $S$ at $p$ and
$$
1 \leq \langle a - p, N(p) \rangle k_i(p), \quad i = 1, 2 \qquad (*)
$$ 
where $k_i$ are the principal curvatures. Keeping in mind that $\langle a - p, N(p) \rangle^2 = |a-p|^2 \leq r^2$, the proof follows bt adding or multiplying the inequalities $(*)$.

My question is:

> Where does $(*)$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\colon S \to \Bbb R$ be given by $f(q) = \|q-a\|^2$. Then since $p$ is a maximum for $f$, you know that if $\alpha\colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to S$ has $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0) = v$, then $$\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}t^2}\bigg|_{t=0} f(\alpha(t)) \leq 0.$$Actually evaluating this gives $$(f\circ\alpha)'(t) = 2\langle \alpha'(t), \alpha(t)-a\rangle  \implies (f\circ \alpha)''(0) =  2\langle \alpha''(0), p-a\rangle  + 2\langle v,v\rangle \leq 0 $$This means that choosing $v$ to be an unit vector, you have $$1 \leq \langle \alpha''(0), a-p\rangle.$$But $p-a$ normalized is precisely $N(p)$, so only the normal part of $\alpha''(0)$ contributes to this product (recognize the definition of normal curvature), and you get $(\ast)$ by letting $v$ be the principal directions.

Comment: In the third math line, you mean $1 \leq \langle \alpha''(0), a-p \rangle$?

Comment: Oh yes. Silly slip-up. Fixed.

Comment: Also, does your conclusion use that $\alpha''(0) = N(p) k_i(p)$? I am struggling with this part

Comment: What we had before was for every unit $v$ right? But $$\langle- dN_{\alpha(t)}(\alpha'(t)),\alpha'(t)\rangle = \langle -(N\circ\alpha)'(t), \alpha'(t) \rangle = \langle N(\alpha(t)),\alpha"(0)\rangle.$$Choose $v$ to be a principal direction above.

Comment: $v$ being a principal direction we get that $k_i =\sigma_p(v,v) = \langle N(p), \alpha''(0) \rangle$, ok with this. On the other hand, $1 \leq \langle \alpha''(0), N(p) \rangle |a-p|$. Ok with this as well. But I am failing to see how to get to the point

Comment: Oh, maybe I see this. Let me write

Comment: We have: $1 \leq k_i |a-p| |N(p)| = k_i \langle N(p), |a-p|N(p) \rangle = k_i \langle N(p), a-p \rangle$. Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: I also think we should take care with the sign of N(p), it could be both $a-p$ or $p-a$, right? I wrote a solution carrying on the $\pm$ sign in front of it that seems to have worked.

Comment: Yes, it should work. $K$ does not depend on the choice of $N$. Also, $H$ does, but $|H|$ does not.

Comment: Yes, but in order to get the result for the modulus I needed the $\pm$.